# HP iPAQ 514 Development with Visual Studio 2005

Tags: windows-mobile, visual-studio-2005, certificate

I can't connect Visual Studio 2005 to HP iPAQ 514. It was a gift to renew my MSDN Subscription.

I can connect prefectly with Active Sync. I use Windows XP SP3.

How can I connect to device with Visual Studio 2005? It said that I need a development certificate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/54cc125e-f6ab-4a52-be50-4dd48b0f1f14)